# WordPress images fail with plugin

Tags: image, wordpress

I'm having a problem with inserting pictures in my posts/pages after working on a plugin that uses the integrated images uploader/media library.

When the pictures are uploaded and put into the post/page, they won't display in either the workarea or in the final post.

When the plugin is deactivated, the image oploader works fine.

There is a reaction in the following file that I can't understand:

```
/var/www/themex/public_html/wp-includes/query.php

 Linie 2390 = $q_status = explode(',', $q['post_status']);
Linie 2399 = if( in_array( $status, $q_status ) ) {
```

What could this be?

Answer (score 0):

Tthis error happened to me when I wrote a plugin that was using the image uploader. Try using the "Browser Uploader" if it work then it is a javascript problem.